# App crashed H10 error code, when uploading to Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mean-stack, mlab

I have a node app, which is running locally without any problem, but when I try to deploy it with heroku, I cannot do it. The error that I get is:

```
2017-05-26T13:37:31.249587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=engageitvisz.herokuapp.com request_id=e9641b76-0667-44ce-b85a-fb431c1cca2a fwd="31.10.149.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I am using the mongoLab at my application, but I added it as addon in heroku. Here is the server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var databaseUrl = "mongodb://user:pass@ds137090.mlab.com:37090/questions"; 
var collections = ["questions"];
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs(databaseUrl, collections);

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5002));

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get('/', function(request, response){
   response.send("Hello from server.js");
});

app.get('/questions', function(request, response){
   console.log("I received a GET request for questions");

db.questions.find(function(err, docs){
  if(err){
         response.send(err);
  }
  response.json(docs);
   })
});
app.post('/questions', function(request, response){
   console.log("I received a POST request for questions");

});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.log('Server running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Procfile:

```
web: node server.js
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "engageit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "EngageIt visualization",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.13.1"
  },
  "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": "https://github.com/VitezKoja92/EngageItVisz.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-prebuild": "echo This runs before Heroku installs your dependencies.",
    "heroku-postbuild": "echo This runs afterwards."
  },
  "author": "Danilo Krasic",
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "express"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.7.2"
  }
}
```

Please, let me know if you have any suggestion, as I am trying to solve this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

- First go to deploy in herkou
- Then go to git hub and fork parse-server-example
- then again go to your heroku dashboard and link your app to your git commit

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a URI connection string that you got straight from MongoLab. Try making sure that you are getting the correct connection URI from the MongoLab Heroku addon by entering the following command at the root of your project as per the Heroku help pages:

[`heroku config:get MONGODB_URI`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#getting-your-connection-uri)